# PHP array to detail record outed same index values

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I got the following out for detail records in Codigniter. (Incorrect Output)

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [voucher_id] => 3
            [vote] => 1089
            [amount] => 10000
            [notes] => test
            [status] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [voucher_id] => 3
            [vote] => 1089
            [amount] => 10000
            [notes] => test
            [status] => 1
        )    
)
```

But I have different values releted to array indexes as follows : (Desired Output)

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [voucher_id] => 3
            [vote] => 1089
            [amount] => 10000
            [notes] => test
            [status] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [voucher_id] => 3
            [vote] => 1090
            [amount] => 5000
            [notes] => test1
            [status] => 1
        )
)
```

I used the following controller code to do this.

$details = [];
if ($this->form_validation->run() == true) {

```
        $count = count($this->input->post('vote'));
        $items = $this->input->post('vote');
        $amt = $this->input->post('amount');
        $notes = $this->input->post('notes');
        

        for ($x = 0; $x <= $count; $x++) {
            $details[$x]['voucher_id'] = $id;
            $details[$x]['vote'] = $items;
            $details[$x]['amount'] = $amt;
            $details[$x]['notes'] = $notes;
            $details[$x]['status'] = 1;
        } 
    }
```

And the view as follows :

### JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var i = 0;
        $(".add-new").click(function () {
            i++;

            $('#addr' + i).html("<td ><a href='javascript:void(0);' id='add-post' class='external add-new'><i style='color: #0066ff !important;' class='fa fa-2x fa-plus-circle'></i></a></td>" +
                "<td><select name='vote" + i + "' id='vote" + i + "' class='select2 form-control' required>" +
                "<option value=''></option>" +
                <?php
                if (!empty($votes_data)) {
                foreach ($votes_data as $row) {

                ?>

                "<option value='<?= $row->vote_id ?>'><?= addslashes($row->vote) ?></option>" +
                <?php
                }
                }

                ?>
                "</select></td>" +
                "<td><input  name='amount" + i + "' type='number'  step='any' placeholder='Amount' class='form-control input-md' required></td>" +
                "<td><input  name='notes" + i + "' type='text' placeholder='Notes' class='form-control input-md'></td>" +
                "<td><a href='javascript:void(0);' class='external remove'><i style='color: #ff6600 !important;' class='fa fa-2x fa-minus-circle' id='addIcon'></i></a></td>");
            $('#tab_logic').append('<tr id="addr' + (i + 1) + '"></tr>');
            $('#i').val(i);
        });

        $(document).on("click", ".remove", function () {
            var count = $('#tab_logic>tbody').children().length;
            if (count > 0) {
                $(this).closest('tr').remove();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

### HTML

```
<div class="col-md-12 column">
                    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="tab_logic">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="text-center" >
                            </th>
                            <th class="text-center" >
                                Vote
                            </th>
                            <th class="text-center" >
                                Paying Amount (Rs.)
                            </th>
                            <th class="text-center" >
                                Notes (If Any)
                            </th>
                            <th class="text-center">
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        <tr id='addr0' >
                            <td>
                                <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="add-post" class="external add-new"><i style="color: #0066ff !important;"
                                                                                      class="fa fa-2x fa-plus-circle"></i></a>
                            </td>
                            <td style="width: 25%">
                                
                                <select name="vote" id="vote" class="form-control select2" required>
                                    <option value=""></option>
                                    <?php
                                    if (!empty($votes_data)) {
                                        foreach ($votes_data as $row) {

                                            ?>

                                            <option value="<?= $row->vote_id ?>"><?= $row->vote ?></option>
                                            <?php
                                        }
                                    }

                                    ?>
                                </select>
                            </td>
                            <td style="width: 20%">
                                <input type="number" step="any" name='amount' id="amount" placeholder='Amount' class="form-control" required/>
                            </td>

                            <td style="width: 45%">
                                <input type="text" name='notes' id="notes" placeholder='Notes' class="form-control"/>
                            </td>
                            
                            
                            <td><a href='javascript:void(0);' class='external '><i style='color: #ff6600 !important;'
                                                                 class='fa fa-2x fa-minus-circle' id='addIcon'></i></a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr id='addr1'></tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

I want to get the desired output as follows :

```
+------------+------+--------+-------+--------+
| voucher_id | vote | amount | notes | status |
+------------+------+--------+-------+--------+
|          3 | 1089 |  10000 | test  |      1 |
|          3 | 1090 |   5000 | test1 |      1 |
+------------+------+--------+-------+--------+
```

But the code inserted following incorrect vlues to the table.

```
  +------------+------+--------+-------+--------+
    | voucher_id | vote | amount | notes | status |
    +------------+------+--------+-------+--------+
    |          3 | 1089 |  10000 | test  |      1 |
    |          3 | 1089 |  10000 | test  |      1 |
    +------------+------+--------+-------+--------+
```

What is going wrong ? Can anyone help ?

Comment: produce the raw sql statement and you will see what is wrong

Comment: @ 
nbk
 . Ok. but how can I produce the raw aql statement, till inserting the values to the table. The code inserted incorrect values to the table as I mentioned in the above table.